# jquery not finding items when routing in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have the following code inside my angular component that is run inside `ngOnInit()`:

```
animateMobileSkillBar() : void {
    console.log("Animation skillbar out");
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      console.log("Animation skillbar inside document ready");
      $(".skillbars").each(function() {
        console.log("Animation skillbar for each skillbar");
        // The stuff I need to do...
      }
    }
}
```

I added the `$(document).ready` because it didn't work before. Now it works on page load. But when I do routing it does not. I know the script is running and I get printed "Animation skillbar inside document ready". So for some reason, the problem is `$(".skillbars").each()`.

Why is this not working? I feel as if the `skillbars` are not ready but that was the goal of `document.ready` right?

Comment: console.log($(".skillbars")); and see what do you get. Also what if you try to call the code after ngAfterViewInit() ? Try doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your implementation into ngAfterViewInit(). where the view will be initialized with all bindings. 
For more information look the link
https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit.

You do not need to do this document.ready.

Comment: Solved. I need to wit 6 mins to mark it as a solution.

Comment: sure, and it's not good practice to use jquery like this in angular code.

Answer (score 1):

Place the code in  ngAfterViewInit() so that the HTML is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Check https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.

`ngOnInit` can be used when you want to do stuff with input properties, etc.. The view is not ready at that state.

Try to put it - without the document.ready stuff - in `ngAfterViewInit`.